# Show that $10^{2008} − 10^{8}$ is divisible by $2008$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that $10^{2008} − 10^{8}$ is divisible by $2008$.   Of course this radiates Fermat's little theorem with $p=251$
And so the first term would be $ 0 \mod 2008$ but how is the $10^{
8}$ divisible by $2008$?

Comment: Well, 10^2008 -10^8 =10^8 (10^2000-1)=2^8 x5^8 (10^2000-1) so it suffices to show 251|10^2000 -1.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $2008=2^3\times251$. Now $251|10^{2000}-1$ and $2^3|10^8$, so $2008|10^{2008}-10^8$.

Comment: How do we know 251 divide (10^2000-1)?

Comment: Let $p$ prime and $a$ such that $\gcd(a,p)=1$ : then if $ \varphi(p)  \mid x $ then $p \mid a^x - 1$  by Euler's generalization of Fermat's little theorem. Now look at $\varphi(251)$ ...

Comment: Now I see by flt 251 divides the second factor ,10^2000-1

Answer (score 0):

$10^{2008}-10^{8}=$

$10^{8}(10^{2000}-1)=$

$10^{8}(10^{1000}+1)(10^{1000}-1)=$

$10^{8}(10^{1000}+1)(10^{500}+1)(10^{500}-1)=$

$10^{8}(10^{1000}+1)(10^{500}+1)(10^{250}+1)(10^{250}-1)$

---

Obviously, $8$ divides $10^{8}$.

By Euler's theorem, $\gcd(10,251)=1\implies10^{\phi(251)}\equiv1\pmod{251}$.

Since $251$ is prime, $\phi(251)=251-1=250$.

Hence $10^{250}\equiv1\pmod{251}$.

Hence $10^{250}-1\equiv0\pmod{251}$.

Hence $251$ divides $10^{250}-1$.

---

So $8$ divides $10^{8}$.

And $251$ divides $10^{250}-1$.

Hence $8\cdot251$ divides $10^{8}(10^{250}-1)$.

Hence $2008$ divides $10^{8}(10^{250}-1)$.

Hence $2008$ divides $10^{8}(10^{1000}+1)(10^{500}+1)(10^{250}+1)(10^{250}-1)$.

Hence $2008$ divides $10^{2008}-10^{8}$.

Comment: :) Nice to see here "FLT" with the meaning of Fermat's ***little*** theorem...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Thanks, though, it's actually Euler's theorem up there (unless I move the "since $251$ is prime" statement prior to the "FLT" statement)...

Comment: Well, I liked the hijacking of the term FLT (as a long term visitor of news::sci.math) ;-) But now I better delete that comments...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Naahhh, just leave it there... I've edited the question, which means that others can see my edit, and along with your comment above, might be enlightened a little further :)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: No need to, because we also have $10^{250}-1$ as part of our product, so it just a tiny typo repeated in several places, which I will fix right away...

Comment: Gottfried Helms at my school I told the teacher the first day I saw him prove Fermat's * little * theorem that he write it as flt since then u see smaller case would mean ' little ' as not to be confused with FLT ! U like ?

Answer (score 0):

Since 251 is prime and by Fermats Little theorem for prime p
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$$

we get

$$ 10^{250} \equiv 1 \mod 251$$
$$ 10^{2000} = (10^{250})^8 \equiv 1 \mod 251$$
$$10^{2008} = 10^{2000}10^8 \equiv 10^8 \mod 251$$
$$ 10^{2008} - 10^8  = 10^{2000}10^8 - 10^8 \equiv 0 \mod 251 $$

therefore $251 \mid 10^{2008} - 10^8$